# Почему Python тормозит?

Tags: python, opencv

Использовал и Jupyter Notebook, и IDLE, результат один. Инициализация камеры идет в течение 10 минут. До этого все выполнялось быстро, но внезапно все начало неимоверно тормозить. Дело не в железе, у меня хороший ПК, и папка с проектом лежит на SSD.

```
import cv2
import os

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 640) # set video width
cam.set(4, 480) # set video height

face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# For each person, enter one numeric face id
face_id = input('\n enter user id end press  ==>  ')

print("\n [INFO] Initializing face capture. Look the camera and wait ...")
# Initialize individual sampling face count
count = 0

while(True):
    ret, img = cam.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, -1) # flip video image vertically
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)     
        count += 1

        # Save the captured image into the datasets folder
        cv2.imwrite("dataset/User." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        cv2.imshow('image', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif count >= 30: # Take 30 face sample and stop video
         break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Кто нибудь знает, в чем проблема? Это только с этим кодом так, остальные выполняются нормально

Comment: если код тормозит, его нужно профилировать и смотреть, какая именно строка/строки вносят максимальное "торможение". И уже показывать этот код с этой строкой.

Comment: может вирус/антивирус ?в диспетчере задач  левых процессов нет ? процесор на скока % в этот момент загружен ?

Comment: В целом python и все, что с ним связано, жрет примерно 40%. Левых процессов нету. Видимо, надо отлаживать